# When I make the clone of a project from bitbucket after successfully clone create when I build the solution its give following error

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When I make the clone of a project from bitbucket after successfully clone create when I build the solution its give following error.

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       The `"Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BuildTasks.Csc"` task could not be loaded from the assembly

`E:\Avinash\BitBucketProject\IntuitiveCrm\IntuitiveCrm\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\build\..\tools\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.CodeAnalysis.dll.`

Could not load file or assembly `'file:///E:\Avinash\BitBucketProject\IntuitiveCrm\IntuitiveCrm\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\tools\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.CodeAnalysis.dll'`
 or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Confirm that the `<UsingTask>` declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements `Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask`.  `IntuitiveCrm.Web`

Answer (score 0):

The error clearly says the solution to your issue also.  The dll is missing.

`Could not load file or assembly 'file:///E:\Avinash\BitBucketProject\IntuitiveCrm\IntuitiveCrm\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\tools\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.CodeAnalysis.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask. IntuitiveCrm.Web`

Just add the dll in the required folder if it is accidentally deleted or missing. It should do the fix.

Comment: Thanks, Dear...Some dll from package folder is missing add those dll and build the solution.

Comment: Good. Glad to help :)